# Remove dovecot emails based on subject

Tags: dovecot, email-bounces

My server just got used as the return address for 100,000 spam emails.

The emails are stacked up in various user's accounts and I want to delete them all.

Is there a way using dovecot 1.1.7 to delete mails containing "Returned mail:" in the subject.  Most likely one user at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Old `dovecot` has no `doveadm` utility so you have to search for messages by some other tools. If your default storage is `maildir` then each message is stored in it's own file. So you can run something like that:

```
egrep -R -l "Returned mail:" /path/mail/* | xargs rm
```

Here `-l` (dash-ell) option force `egrep` to print the names of files containing the given pattern. That names are passed to the `xargs` utility that appends filenames to the invocation of the `rm` utility.

The exact result of the command depend on the lot of circumstances so my advise is to backup the whole mail storage before experiments.

If your storage is `mbox` where all the messages are stored within one huge file then there is no easy CLI-way to clean up the mess. The only approach I know is to use some pop/imap client like `ThunderBird` that can manage messages within mboxes.